# If we developed website in Outsystems, Then how can we deploy it under our personal domain like example.com

Tags: outsystems

I'm developing a web application in Outsystems. But I didn't see anywhere the option of getting it's compiled source code to deploy on my other server.

Is there any way to do so if not then how can we achieve it?

Same for the mobile app, can we get APK from outsystems IDE?

Comment: Please be more specific and keep you question to a single topic

Comment: what is wrong here, Tell me. It's specific to outsystem only.
Please, It's very basic question, That I didn't find anywhere, By giving -ve marking do not create it's feel bad. Please. If anything wrong I'm here to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all to answer your questions, you can't get the source code (C#, ASP.NET, HTML and etc.) that you've made in Outsystems. However the "code" that you've made are stored as certain Outsystems file types and can be found in the service center.

.OAP Outsystems application (bundle of modules & extensions)

.OML Outsystems module/eSpace

.XIF Extensions (This is c# or java code what you've made yourself)

.OSP Solution (Bundle of modules/espaces and extensions)

In Outsystems you have two options of deploying, via Lifetime or via the service center. How Lifetime works you can find with this link: https://www.outsystems.com/videos/lifetime-application-deployment/. Summarized Lifetime provides you a user friendly overview to deploy to another environments and checks if there are broken references between modules/eSpaces.

If you want to deploy via the servicecenter, go to the tab "Factory". In the menu below the tabs you will see "applications", "eSpaces" & etc. If you click on one you can publish applications, modules, etc.

What also important is, when you want to publish a application, module, extension or solution to another Outsystems infrastructure (with a different activation code). You need to use the IPP portal of Outsystems since your code is licensed for your own infrastructure. More information about this you will find here: https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Licensing/Intellectual_Property_Protection_(IPP)

Answer (score 2):

Code developed in Outsystems cannot be easily changed from server to server unless they belong to the same license. If they do belong to the same license, the easy way is to use Lifetime to deploy it from one to the other. If Lifetime is not available, then you can download the solution from one server and upload the solution file in the other server using ServiceCenter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pedro.

I'm totally new in OutSystems. I didn't get what you said, means, programmatically. 
Is there any documentation for the same anywhere? or can you please elaborate bit more.